# use TryParseExact to format an integer value as a time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting, tryparse

I have an integer that will have the value of a year month and day. For example 20110504.

I am using `TryPareseExact` to format it into `yyyy-MM-dd` but it is not working.

Here is my function

```
public DateTime DateDisplay(int date)
{
    DateTime dateValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
        return dateValue;
    else
        return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

It always go to the else and returns `DateTime.MinValue`. I want the date to be look like 2011/05/04. Would you be able to help me to identify where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the format string should be `"yyyyMMdd"` if your input string has no hyphens.

Comment: it work but the output is 2011/05/04 12:00:00 how i can get the time out and only keep the date?

Comment: A `DateTime` always contains a time portion. If you want to display only the date, you control that with your output string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx